# Error 1146 table doesn't exist and I cannot delete the table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

In phpmyadmin there's a list of tables in my database which show up on the left hand side but they don't all show up on the right hand side.

When I click spme of these tables on the left hand side I get

> "error 1146 table doesn't exist"

I cannot delete the table as it doesn't show up in the right hand side for me to delete it.

Please help me get the tables back or delete it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
```

and then check.

Comment: I'm on windows and I'm using wamp. What do I put in my path?

Comment: Well, develop in windows is a crazy thing. Uninstall wampp and reinstall it. Save the database first.

Comment: I can't save the database because when I export, lots of my database tables are missing. If I reinstall wamp I'll be left with none of my databases or tables once it's installed. I want to recover my database tables or delete the database tables.